# I am only getting one row when using JSON SERDE to read a json file

Tags: json, hive, hive-serde

JSON Data:

```
[{
  "liked": "true",
  "user_id": "101",
  "video_end_type": "3",
  "minutes_played": "3",
  "video_id": "101",
  "geo_cd": "AP",
  "channel_id": "11",
  "creator_id": "101",
  "timestamp": "07/05/2019 01:36:35",
  "disliked": "true"
},
{
"liked": true, 
"user_id": 102, 
"video_end_type": null,
 "minutes_played": 4,
 "video_id": 102, 
"geo_cd": "AP",
 "channel_id": 12,
 "creator_id": 102,
 "timestamp": "15/04/2019 17:04:00", 
"disliked": true
}
]
```

Output:

```
hive> select * from stream;
OK
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
true    101     3       3       101     AP      11      101     NULL    true
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The output I get is only the first line.

Code:

```
add jar json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

create external table stream(
    liked string, user_id int, video_end_type int, minutes_played int, video_id int, geo_cd string, channel_id int, creator_id int, time timestamp, disliked 
string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    LOCATION '/location';
```

Note: I can't remove the brackets because then the data is not in correct JSON format.

Comment: Your json data format is incorrect. The json encoded data should be in a format as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html)
Make sure you are cleaning up the data before loading into hive table

Comment: Hi Prabhat,

My data is exactly in the format :

[
   {
     "ItemId": 6789,
     "OrderDate": "11/11/2017" 
   },
   {
     "ItemId": 4352,
     "OrderDate": "12/12/2017"
   }
  ]

Are you saying I need to use struct<> to read the data like in documentation or if the format is wrong can you help me with the correct one.

Comment: The expected format is as below:
{
"DocId": "AWS",
"User": {
        "Id": 1234,
        "Username": "bob1234", 
        "Name": "Bob",
"ShippingAddress": {
"Address1": "123 Main St.",
"Address2": null,
"City": "Seattle",
"State": "WA"
   },
"Orders": [
   {
     "ItemId": 6789,
     "OrderDate": "11/11/2017" 
   },
   {
     "ItemId": 4352,
     "OrderDate": "12/12/2017"
   }
  ]
 }
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply prabhat, can you please convert my data in the required format. I am having trouble with it. Please.

Comment: If the below answer helped, accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar would work for you:

JSON DATA:

```
{"liked": "true",  "user_id": "101",  "video_end_type": "3",  "minutes_played": "3",  "video_id": "101",  "geo_cd": "AP",  "channel_id": "11",  "creator_id": "101",  "timestamp": "07/05/2019 01:36:35",  "disliked": "true"}
{"liked": true, "user_id": 102, "video_end_type": null, "minutes_played": 4, "video_id": 102, "geo_cd": "AP", "channel_id": 12, "creator_id": 102, "timestamp": "15/04/2019 17:04:00", "disliked": true}
```

And your create query should be as below:

```
create external table stream(
liked string,
user_id string,
video_end_type string,
minutes_played string,
video_id string,
geo_cd string,
channel_id string,
creator_id string,
`timestamp` string,
disliked string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/location/';
```

**Note:** If your JSON data is consistent, you can use appropriate datatypes instead of string.